# IO port register sizing and how device recognise address is for it

Tags: io, architecture, x86, x86-64, cpu-architecture

I read in a article about that 64k io port each are address assigned to 8bit register and when you combine io port together you get 16 bit,32bit etc. Sorry i am not getting that website in my history now so i cant provide link.
I just not understood what it want to say so i just put the raw form here

So there are mine few points that i want confirmation on as i am confused bcoz as i accidently land on another website they have just another idea.

i) i/o ports are assigned to `registers` of peripherals. These are of 16bit as there are 64k port and register they are assigned to can be of any size(8,16,32,64bit).

ii)Except for pci related devices io port address number are fixed,but as in device with configuration space register can be assigned io address number using bar any number one want just i should not be used by anyother device.

Que1)When a address come out of processor it goes to motherboard through northbridge/system_agent and it routes it according to address map it has, peripheral device are told to accept i/o range or memory address range on basis of what was configured in bar,but as northbridge is made up of many controller [like memory,graphics,pci etc] but it is who, who has address mapping to route.

queii) according to [intel 82815 gmch northbridge](https://download.intel.com/design/chipsets/datashts/29068801.pdf) page 129 section 4.3

> "The processor allows 64K+3 bytes to be addressed within the I/O
> space. The GMCH propagates the processor I/O address without any
> translation on to the destination bus"

What does this means it only routes mmio and io bar but than how rest of io address(that are not assigned by software or due to i/o bar register) are decided. where should they go how peripheral device know this address it should acccept,if they are just thrown on the bus than how CS pin is decided of particular device

Comment: Yes, I/O space is byte-addressable, so 4-byte IO registers need to have port numbers separated by 4 to not overlap.  (I think they also need to be naturally-aligned.)

Comment: But "
01F0 r/w data register" is data register of hard disk and is 4 bytes in size.

Comment: And another 
"01F1 r error register" this one is error register

Comment: And these port number are not seperated

Comment: Actually this website told it to be aligned and there are many which say it's just a address of io register and one address for one register and register can be of any size

Comment: Oh, maybe I'm mistaken about separation, then.  If the address and size are just signalled on the bus separately, devices can decode and check for exact match against a specific port number regardless of width.  It's IO registers, not memory, so you wouldn't expect / want a 1-byte IO to 01F1 to interact with the 2nd byte of a 4-byte register at 01F0.  (Fun fact: ancient systems like 8086 used a shared bus where memory and IO shared the same address lines, with a signal that indicated whether it was IO or memory.)

Comment: Thanks for being there to solve my doubts.If you not know some topic you even search for it am I right. Thanks a lot,very much for giving your time

Comment: Yeah, often I quickly google something to double-check, since wrong comments can mislead future readers.  I didn't this time, though, I'm partly guessing about how things work, but the proposed decoding of address and size seems obviously sensible.

Comment: But nowadays too same address lines are used just a signal to say whether address is of memory or io. That day you helped i searched a lot about every topic related to io

Comment: In modern CPUs, no, there isn't an external bus shared between memory and I/O.  And with PCIe being separate point-to-point links instead of a shared bus, something must direct a packet to the right link (where the device with that I/O port is), probably not broadcasting over every link.  But older PCI was a shared bus.

Comment: Srry I am talking about pci bus not pcie

Comment: As pcie and usb uses direct one to one connection

Comment: Please don't write multiple tiny comments, unless they're separate ideas.  Anyway, for PCIe, it's still a separate bus from memory.  Older systems like Core2 and before had a FSB and a northbridge that would decode messages as IO/MMIO for PCI or memory for DRAM, but modern CPUs have the memory controller integrated, so DRAM ranges of physical address space are separated out and directed there inside the CPU, on the ring bus.  See [this](https://superuser.com/q/1226197) and https://www.servethehome.com/things-are-getting-meshy-next-generation-intel-skylake-sp-cpus-mesh-architecture/

Comment: Srry i am wrong habitat to do silly mistake